# How to make page/post password protected so you must reenter everytime you visit the page?

Tags: cache, password, session

I added the following to the child-theme functions.php

`///time out login so you must reenter it every time//
add_action( 'wp', 'post_pw_sess_expire' );
    function post_pw_sess_expire() {
    if ( isset( $_COOKIE['wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH] ) )
    // Setting a time of 0 in setcookie() forces the cookie to expire with the session
    setcookie('wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH, $_COOKIE['wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH], time() + 1 * 5, COOKIEPATH);
}`

I replaced 

`setcookie('wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH, '', 0, COOKIEPATH);`

with

`setcookie('wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH, $_COOKIE['wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH], time() + 1 * 5, COOKIEPATH);`

so that you must reenter the password after one minute on the page/per session.

If I open Chrome, go to the page, I go to http://happynick.com/marketing/extra/private/ and type "private" to enter page.

When I "Clear Browsing Data" and go back to http://happynick.com/marketing/extra/private/, I am asked to enter "private" each time. Great. But if I go back to the page without closing Chrome, I can still access the page WITHOUT being asked to enter the password.

In Firefox, I can access it without entering the password again, even after closing Firefox and clearing going to Preferences > Advanced > Cached Web Content > Clear now.

Answer (score 7):

Stop what you're doing - it's so much simpler!

```
function wpse_191369_post_password_expires() {
    return time() + 10; // Expire in 10 seconds
}

add_filter( 'post_password_expires', 'wpse_191369_post_password_expires' );
```

That's all you need.

Comment: Thanks, but will this work with other pages? wpse_191369 looks it might only work on this page. How did you discover this number? Is this correct `///time out login so you must reenter it every time// add_action( 'wp', 'post_pw_sess_expire' );

function wpse_191369_post_password_expires() {
    return time() + 10; // Expire in 10 seconds
}

add_filter( 'post_password_expires', 'wpse_191369_post_password_expires' );
}`

Comment: wpse_191369 is a prefix I use when naming functions in answers - WPSE = WordPress Stack Exchange, 191369 = the ID of this question. My answer is all the code you need. It overrides the default cookie timeout for *all* post passwords. You don't need to handle the cookie/password yourself i.e. You don't need `post_pw_sess_expire` or any of the code you've tried so far.

Comment: Which Is this correct?

///time out login so you must reenter it every time// 
add_action( 'wp', 'post_pw_sess_expire' ); 
function post_password_expires() { return time() + 10; // Expire in 10 seconds } add_filter( 'post_password_expires', 'post_password_expires' ); }

Comment: The following did not work. Help.